# How to store 500 sorted integers (uint64) efficiently?

Tags: integer, compression

1. I don't care about speed, I just want less storage space.
2. I need to restore 500 integers.

I have considered some compress algorithms, such as gzip/deflate, variable-length integers, and bitmaps.

Obviously, bitmaps are not suitable, because I am only storing 500 integers, but I need `math.MaxUint64` bits to construct the bitmap.

Are there some special algorithms that have good performance with respect to saving storage space?

There are 500 sorted integers, where any integer is smaller than 10,000,000.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are all less than 10,000,000, you can get a 62.5% reduction by simply storing your integers in 24 bits instead of 64 bits. Write the low three bytes of each integer. That would be 1500 bytes instead of 4000 bytes. You could do a little better by storing three of your integers in 70 bits. That would take it down to 1459 bytes.

There is some gain possible from the fact they are sorted, where the theoretical maximum would be a reduction of 470 bytes. You can start on that with delta coding, where you write the first integer as is, and the remainder as the difference between that integer and the previous one. You would then need a scheme to write those differences in fewer than 24 bits each on average. A variable-length integer approach may get you some gain there.

I tried a simple variable-length-integer scheme where I stored a delta in two bytes if it was less than 32768, three bytes if less than 4194304, and four bytes otherwise. The second and third bytes each have one bit reserved to indicate whether or not there is one more byte.

That resulted in 1098±21 bytes for 500 randomly chosen and then sorted integers less than 10,000,000. Not too bad, since the theoretical minimum for that would be 983 bytes.